# Cannot discriminate `0 = 1`

Tags: coq, tactic, coq-unimath

I am just practicing a bit with coq, doing some [UniMath exercises](https://unimath.github.io/Schools/2019-04-Birmingham/Part1_Spartan_Type_Theory/Spartan_exercises.html) and am trying to prove `(0 = 1) -> empty`. However, for some reason, I seem unable to reason based on `0 = 1`:

```
Require Import UniMath.Foundations.PartD.

Theorem exercise_1_3 : (0 = 1) → empty.
Proof.
  intros contra.
  exfalso.
  discriminate contra.
Qed.
```

The discriminate line gives the error `No primitive equality found.`

Comment: Have you tried just `discriminate`?

Comment: `intros contra. discriminate.` gives the same result

Comment: I don't know anything about UniMath in particular, but I believe `discriminate` is not designed univalently, so it may not work.  I don't know what the authors of those exercises recommended, but the standard way to prove this "by hand" is a simplified version of the encode-decode method.

Comment: Oh, I see now that there are [solutions](https://github.com/UniMath/Schools/blob/master/2019-04-Birmingham/Part1_Spartan_Type_Theory/Spartan_solutions.v). These solve the entire exercise by `exact (λ p, transportf (nat_rect (λ _, UU) unit (λ _ _, empty)) p tt).` It will take some time to unpack that, but at least I have a solution now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UniMath [redefines the notation](https://github.com/UniMath/UniMath/blob/ffa78dfadb6c336b7e3e78d54a663b1c05ca6eed/UniMath/Foundations/Preamble.v#L142) `x = y` away from Coq's standard `eq` (without also replacing `discriminate`), so `discriminate` doesn't work. You can consider `discriminate` to be a specialized variant of `injection`, which you can consider further to be a specialized variant of `inversion`, which should work here (as UniMath's `=` is still just an `Inductive`, and with the same definition as `eq` at that).

```
Theorem exercise_1_3 : (0 = 1) → empty.
Proof.
  intros contra.
  exfalso.
  inversion contra.
Qed.
```

Or you can manually replicate the proof generated by `discriminate`, which [UniMath sort of does here](https://github.com/UniMath/UniMath/blob/ffa78dfadb6c336b7e3e78d54a663b1c05ca6eed/UniMath/Foundations/NaturalNumbers.v#L74-L78). The idea is this: the most fundamental representation of the fact that `O` and `S O` are different is that `nat` has a `match`ing principle that lets you make a computational decision based on `O` vs. `S O` (without requiring that the results of that decision be equal anyway, as a higher inductive might demand). So construct a function `P` satisfying `P O := unit; P (S O) := empty`, and then use `O = S O` to rewrite `tt : P O` into an `P (S O)`.

```
Theorem exercise_1_3 : (0 = 1) → empty.
Proof.
  intros contra.
  pose (P n := match n with | O => unit | S _ => empty end).
  change (P 1).
  destruct contra.
  constructor.
Qed.
(* The resulting proof is basically the one you commented *)
```